# How do I fill up a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list

How do I fill up a list of lists in python?

Say I'm in a loop and have a function which returns:

```
   returned_list = [ 2, 7, 4]
```

I want to create a new list of lists which looks like:

```
listoflist = [[2, 0, 0],
              [7, 0, 0],
              [4, 0, 0]]
```

In the next iteration of the loop, say the returned_list is:

```
returned_list = [12, 44, 9]
```

Then the listoflist would be updated as:

```
listoflist = [[2, 12, 0],
              [7, 44, 0],
              [4, 9, 0]]
```

How do I define listoflist and how do I take values from returned_list and put them in that order in Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the list.append() function to append the list to your *listoflist*.

```
    listoflist = []

    while(...) {
       returned_list = function()  #This function returns the list
       listoflist.append(returned_list)    
    }
```

Comment: I think that returns
{
[[2, 7, 4],
 [12, 44, 9],
 [0, 0, 0]]

Comment: @Shubhojit No, I checked. It returns what is required. [[2, 12, 0], [7, 44, 0], [4, 9, 0]]